# Need to store a 2d list but not using array

Tags: java, 2d, store

Consider that I have a txt file containing data of the following format:

```
"Home" "A1"
"Car" "A2"
"Home" "B1"
"Home" "A1"
"Car" "A2"
"Man" "B1"
```

How I can store this kind of data and also in sorted format, without duplicate data? But The first and third element must not be deleted as they are different with 2nd parameter (repetition of second parameter is allowed but not both 1st and 2nd).

Please suggest any better collection from Java suitable. Also please give an example as I am new to Java.

Comment: re "ASAP": You would be wise not to state this in your posts. Even if it is urgent to you, realize that it is not urgent to us. Many here take offense to this as it implies to them that a) the poster thinks that his post is more important than everyone else's (and it isn't since **all** questions here are equally important), and b) that the poster wants to put pressure on the volunteers who come here to help on their own free time.  Just a friendly word of advice.

Comment: I've never used them myself, but a map might work.

Comment: It is worth noting that a) it's not urgent to any one else, b) you get what you paid for and more. c) you should just use a Set if you want a collection without duplicates.

Comment: Define your own class which holds your text file values and by implementing Comparable interface you make your class sort able.

Answer (score 2):

Best option in Java is a `Map<String, String>`.

As is so urgent, take a look by yourself in the [MAP API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and in this [Google search](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=map%20with%20repeated%20keys%20java)

Also you can use [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), be my guest and take a look into this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend  `Map<String, String>`. If you have time, read [THIS](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/)