# How to read nextline of textfile in Java?

Tags: java, file, line, file-handling

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class stringstore
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\a.txt");
        try
        {
            String strIP="";
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String str[] = line.split(", ");
                strIP = str[0];
            }
            System.out.println(strIP);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        // work with the errors here
        }
    }
}
```

How do I read a nextline from a textfile and display it.

Comment: re "Urgent/ASAP" (source: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140476/need-to-store-a-2d-list-but-not-using-array#comment52170418_32140476)): "You would be wise not to state this in your posts. Even if it is urgent to you, realize that it is not urgent to us. Many here take offense to this as it implies to them that a) the poster thinks that his post is more important than everyone else's (and it isn't since **all** questions here are equally important), and b) that the poster wants to put pressure on the volunteers who come here to help on their own free time."

Comment: Your own code already shows how to use Scanner's nextLine method. And you already know how to use println. So where is the confusion?

Comment: BTW `hasNext()` is testing if there is next token (word) in text. If after last word there would be two empty lines `hasNext()` will return `false`. Use `hasNextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is only slight mistake in your code.
Try this.

```
import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;
   public class stringstore
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File file = new File("C:\\a.txt");
 try
{
String strIP="";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String str[] = line.split(", ");
    strIP = str[0];
System.out.println(strIP);
}

}
catch(IOException e)
{
  // work with the errors here
}
  }
}
```

place the print statement inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can read file line by line:

```
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("filename")));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```