# Json Object not Displaying in Java

Tags: java, json

I want to get "weather" data from JSONObject but this error is coming.

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["weather"] not a string.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:639)
    at GetWeather.main(GetWeather.java:49)
```

This is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class GetWeather {       

    public static String getWeather(String args){
        String result =" ";
        URL url ;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            url = new URL(args);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data= reader.read();
            while(data!=-1){
                char current=(char) data;
                result += current;
                data= reader.read();
            }
            return result;
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //main
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s1 = getWeather(args[0]);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s1);
            String weather= jsonObject.getString("weather");
            System.out.println(weather);
        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the string which I am passing

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Delhi&APPID=04b767167643ea6af521695e7948e0fb
```

This is the data I get back

```
{"coord":{"lon":77.22,"lat":28.67},"weather":[{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":305.86,"pressure":1007,"humidity":38,"temp_min":304.15,"temp_max":307.15},"visibility":3500,"wind":{"speed":1.5,"deg":320},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1508241600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":7808,"message":0.0051,"country":"IN","sunrise":1508201604,"sunset":1508242734},"id":1273294,"name":"Delhi","cod":200}
```

Which in formatted version looks like

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 77.22,
        "lat": 28.67
    },
    "weather": [{
            "id": 721,
            "main": "Haze",
            "description": "haze",
            "icon": "50d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 305.86,
        "pressure": 1007,
        "humidity": 38,
        "temp_min": 304.15,
        "temp_max": 307.15
    },
    "visibility": 3500,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.5,
        "deg": 320
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1508241600,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7808,
        "message": 0.0051,
        "country": "IN",
        "sunrise": 1508201604,
        "sunset": 1508242734
    },
    "id": 1273294,
    "name": "Delhi",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Please tell me whats wrong with my code and what to do.

Comment: "weather" key doesn't hold String value, but array `[....]` so `getString("weather")` is not proper way to pick an array. Have you tried something like `getJSONArray`?

Comment: So you shouldn't use `getString()`

Comment: Thanks, @Pshemo It worked can you tell me the way by which I can extract Temperature and pressure from it?

Comment: Thanks, @Neo It worked can you tell me the way by which I can extract Temperature and pressure from it?

Comment: I formatted your question to add more readable version of your JSON. I also removed ASAP since it is not really necessary in the question (and is quite good down-vote magnet because of reasons explained at: [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140476/need-to-store-a-2d-list-but-not-using-array#comment52170418_32140476))

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo , I wont repeat this mistake again :)

Answer (score 1):

The value of "weather" that you're trying to get is not a `String`, but a `JSONArray`.

In order to read all the information inside it, try using `getJSONArray()`:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s1);
    // read the `weather` content
    JSONArray weatherArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
    // get only the first element of `weather`, the only one existing
    JSONObject weatherObject = (JSONObject)weatherArray.get(0);
    // read all its' properties
    for (Object key : weatherObject.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("key:" + key + ", value: " + weatherObject.get((String)key));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For other info like "temp" or "pressure", just use `getJSONObject()` since "main" has `JSONObject` type:

```
 JSONObject mainObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
 System.out.println("pressure value: " + mainObject.get("pressure"));
 System.out.println("temp value: " + mainObject.get("temp"));
```