# to print all the words in a string which starts and ends with same letter in java

Tags: java

*

```
import java.util.*;
class Word{
  void main(){
    char ch='\u0000',firstc,lastc;
    int c=0,lw; String w="",s1="";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    String n = in.nextLine();n=n+"";
    for (int i=0;i<n.length();i++){
      ch = n.charAt(i);
      if(ch!=' '){
        w=w+ch;
      }else{
        firstc = w.charAt(0);
        lastc = w.charAt(w.length()-1);
        if(firstc==(lastc))
        s1=s1+w;
        System.out.println(""+s1);
      }
    }
    w=" ";
  }
}
```

*
Now the output comes for one string like if I give MADAM HAVE A MODEM as input it only gives me MADAM as output.

Comment: Did you have a question? Also, as an aside: "help me fast" is a good way to get a ticket on the downvote train.

Comment: Lack of indentation makes your code very hard to read. Use [edit] option and post properly indented code.

Comment: Also about "Urgent/ASAP/help me fast" (source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140476/need-to-store-a-2d-list-but-not-using-array#comment52170418_32140476)): "You would be wise not to state this in your posts. Even if it is urgent to you, realize that it is not urgent to us. Many here take offense to this as it implies to them that a) the poster thinks that his post is more important than everyone else's (and it isn't since **all** questions here are equally important), and b) that the poster wants to put pressure on the volunteers who come here to help on their own free time."

Comment: Se also: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: You need the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the string into individual words. Or just read one word at a time from `System.in`

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your "in" string by spaces " ".

After that, if both characters at the start and at the end.
Notice String.charAt() method will get characters from position 0 (start) to the string lenght - 1.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    String n = in.nextLine();
    String[] parts = n.split(" ");
    for(String part : parts) {
        if(part.charAt(0)==part.charAt(part.length()-1)) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually we can't use split function

Comment: It will be great that you say that on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated. It would be much simpler to either `split` the string on space or just read one word at a time:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (in.hasNext()) {
    // Get next word
    String s = in.next();
    if (Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0)) == Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(s.length() - 1))) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

But back to your code, I see these issues.

1. It will always skip the last word
2. You reset `w` outside of the `for` and it should be `w = "";`
3. Your indentation is really bad

Your code fixed (well, at least working):

```
char firstc, lastc;
String w = "";
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a String");
String n = in.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
    ch = n.charAt(i);
    if (ch != ' '){
        w = w + ch;
    }
    if (ch == ' ' ||  i == n.length()-1) {
        firstc = w.charAt(0);
        lastc = w.charAt(w.length()-1);
        if (firstc == lastc) {
            System.out.println(w);
        }
        w="";
    }
}
```